# Any chance may C#/JIT compiler remove the lines which contain assigning a variable to a property, which is not used later?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have the following code:

```
var ad = product.AttributesDictionary;
var ddl = product.DetailedDescriptionList;
var rdl = product.RelatedProductList;
```

I have read that the C#/JIT compiler can do a lot of optimizations. Since the variable are **not used** after the assignment. I fear the C#/JIT compiler might omit these lines for optimizations.

Please don't tell me to remove this line.

**Update:** I think no one is able to understand what I mean. My question is that **if you assign a property to a variable** and then **don't use this variable**, will the C#/JIT compiler omit this code or not?

Comment: Elaborate on what you're trying to achieve by doing this. There's almost definitely a better way of doing this validation than just probing property accessors for exceptions.

Comment: @AntP, my question is not about logic. My question is that whether the C# compiler omit these lines or not?

Comment: The compiler can only perform optimziations that do not change the observable behavior of the program. If the asignment can throw an exception, it cannot be optimzed away even if the assigned value is not used.

Of course, it can optimize away the variable and only call the property getter without storing the result.

But you really shouldn't use exceptions for flow control.

Comment: @Kobi, yes in an application that have some behavior that I want to make sure that it is not omitted.

Comment: @Henrik, my only concern is that whether the C# compiler omit these lines for optimization. Yes or No. It has nothing to do with try/catch or logic inside the property

Comment: If you are trying to initialize a flyweight cache forcibly with a dummy call, then you can try `ToString()`, like `product.AttributesDictionary.ToString();` I believe compiler won't omit that line.

Comment: @MehmetAtaş, are you sure? Then post the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This is not specific to the C# compliler, it's just a general observation)

Assigning a property to a variable has actually two parts:

1. Executing the get method of the property
2. Assigning the return value of the method to the variable.

Since the first part can be as complex as any method, and have plenty of side-effects, no compiler ever will optimize it away.

If the variable is not used after the assignment the second part can be optimized, if the compiler is optimizing aggressively.

---

However, there is another kind of optimizer that behaves way less predictably - the next developer that sees that code.

Those line look like they don't do anything, so if the next person that sees them is a pedant that hates superfluous code (as most developers are), those lines could be deleted without a second glance.

Try to find a better - more explicit - way to accomplish whatever you are trying to accomplish with those lines;

Comment: It's very hard to Accept a single answer from a series of good answers. Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to initialize a flyweight cache forcibly with a dummy call, then you can try `ToString()`, like `product.AttributesDictionary.ToString();` I believe compiler won't omit that line. You may need to check if `product.AttributesDictionary` is null or not depending on cache's behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's see what the spec says about this:

#### Section 3.10: Execution order

> Execution of a C# program proceeds such that the side effects of each
>   executing thread are preserved at critical execution points. A side
>   effect is defined as a read or write of a volatile field, a write to a
>   non-volatile variable, a write to an external resource, and the
>   throwing of an exception.
>
> [..]
>
> Additionally, the execution environment need not evaluate part of an
>   expression if it can deduce that that expression’s value is not used
>   and that no needed side effects are produced (including any caused by
>   calling a method or accessing a volatile field).

Since it is evidently possible that your code throws an exception, it would be a compiler bug if the accesses were optimized away.

So this code is technically safe. Throwing exceptions from an accessor agrees not only with the letter of the law, but also with the spirit: accessors are methods, and methods can certainly be expected to throw depending on the particulars.

However, on the human-facing side of this code things don't look good. If there is a reasonable expectation that you would want to check something, your code should enable this:

```
obj.TrySomething()
```

It should *not* require you to do this:

```
try { obj.DoSomething(); }
catch (SomeException e) { ... }
```

Comment: It's very hard to Accept a single answer from a series of good answers. Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer by compiling this code into an assembly (DLL or EXE) and then using [ILDASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx) to convert it into plain text IL.

This will still not tell you exactly what happens at runtime because the JIT turns the IL into x86/x64 machine code. But the Visual Studio debugger shows you disassembly for that, allowing you to dig further.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it, with this code:

```
public class Example
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    public static void DoSomething(Example instance)
    {
        var value = instance.SomeProperty;
    }
}
```

The method `DoSomething` compiles to the following IL (courtesy of ILSpy):

```
.method public hidebysig static 
    void DoSomething (
        class Example 'instance'
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2061
    // Code size 8 (0x8)
    .maxstack 8
    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: callvirt instance string Example::get_SomeProperty()
    IL_0006: pop
    IL_0007: ret
} // end of method Example::DoSomething
```

You will see that the property accessor, `get_SomeProperty()` is called, even in the case of the most basic property accessor that one can write, and when the type is defined in the same assembly.

Comment: Just curious to know whether you used Release or Debug mode.

Comment: @user960567: I used the "Optimize code" setting (enabled by default in Release mode) in Visual Studio. Without it, the `value` local variable would still be present.

Comment: It's very hard to Accept a single answer from a series of good answers. Thanks All